# .htaccess Load as another file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set up my htaccess to allow me to go to domain.com/file.html and have it load up otherdomain.com/file.html

Here's my current htaccess file, but when it runs, it just redirects me to the other file.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule file.html http://mydomain.com/file.html [L]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `mod_proxy` for that, which you request (assuming you have that module loaded) with [the `P` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).

```
RewriteRule file.html http://mydomain.com/file.html [P]
```

Note that P implies L.

Comment: is there any way to mask url without mod_proxy... am using shared hosting

Comment: @Vignesh You need mod_proxy if the URL is located on a different server. Other than that, you could use <iframe> or other HTML tricks...

Comment: no no i hate that iframes... my blog page is mysite.com/blog.php
i want to use that in blog.mysite.com

Comment: @Vignesh sounds like you might just need to adjust your vhost config to have the right index setting.  Questions like this probably now belong on another site in the network, [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)—probably best to head over there. Or Maybe Serverfault, I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

-- My answer is not entirely correct. See derobert's answer instead --

The most you can do is redirect to that other domain. "Masking" the host name is not possible with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^file.html http://myotherdomain.com/file.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Sure it is. You just need to have `mod_proxy` loaded as well.