# htacess Redirect request for pdf to another domain with the pdf; Mask domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I do a lot of php but I have to admit every time I get into htaccess I get confused.  Can anyone help with the following? 
Note in the following examples the names of the pdfs appended to the url's are generated dynamically.

User requests: 
abc.com/uploads/pdfs/worlds_most_informative.pdf.

The actual location of the pdf is at:
xyz.com/uploads/pdfs/worlds_most_informative.pdf.

I need to have it so when the pdf opens in the browser the user still sees: abc.com/uploads/pdfs/worlds_most_informative.pdf in the browser address bar.

I have tried in vain to adapt some of the other answers, but without success. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a reliable way to do that, since you want the browser to display a URL from a different domain than what they requested. That would be a huge security risk if the browsers supported that, as phishing sites would love to have their victim think they are looking at one domain while content is served from another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363254/htaccess-load-as-another-file)

Comment: Alvaro-Thanks for your input. It's similar to other questions but is not a duplicate to the question you note because that is directing a known file name. These file names are generated by the code.

Comment: Brian- Good point.  That's actually my problem in the first place. One of my customers has multiple domains and I have one set up as the administrative domain where users can log in and upload files.  However you can't upload files to other domains. So far I have avoided having to create multiple admin pages for other domains but as you say there may be no work around for this.

Comment: @noCodeMonkeys. Did you read the accepted answer on that question? It has a link to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) of the `RewriteRule Flags`. There you can see that you could specify a `regex` so all your PDF files get affected.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you can follow the instructions of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363254/htaccess-load-as-another-file) and use `mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy` together.

```
RewriteRule ^uploads/pdfs/(.*)\.pdf$ hhttp://example.org/uploads/pdfs/$1.pdf [P] [P]
```

This way it doesn't matter if the name of the file is dynamically generated, because the regex uses matching groups.